# How can I choose the projection and orthogonal map from $\mathbb{C}^3$ to its subspace?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V_0,V_1,V_2$ be subspaces  of $\mathbb{C}^3$ generated by $(1,1,1),(-1,0,1),(-1,1,0)$, respectively.

If $T_0:\mathbb{C}^3\to V_0 $, $T_1:\mathbb{C}^3\to V_1 $ and $T_2:\mathbb{C}^3\to V_2 $are the projection and orthogonal linear maps? What are the $T_0(x,y,z)$ , $T_1(x,y,z)$ and $T_2(x,y,z)$?
How can I prove that :
$T_0+T_1+T_2=I_3$ and $(T_0)(T_1)=(T_0)(T_2)=(T_1)(T_2)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a unit vector on the line $\;V_0\;$, say $\;u^t:=\frac1{\sqrt3}(1,1,1)\;$ , then

$$P_0:=uu^t=\frac13\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}(1,1,1)=\frac13\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus, for every vector in $\;\Bbb C^3\;$ expressed as a linear combination of the given basis of those subspaces $\;\{\,(1,1,1),\,(\!-1,-,1),\,(\!-1,1,0)\,\}\;$, we get that

$$T\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=P_0\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\frac13\begin{pmatrix}x+y+z\\x+y+z\\x+y+z\end{pmatrix}$$

Observe that $\;P_0^2=P_0\;,\;\;P_0w\in V_0\;\;\forall w\in\Bbb C^3\;$ , and if

$$v\in V_0\iff v=\begin{pmatrix}a\\a\\a\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\text{then}\;\;P_0v=v$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. You solved my big problem. If I need to understand what you write, what should I look for? What is a good book for this subject? Is $T: \mathbb{C}^3 \to V_1$ have the same definition?

Comment: I think that even in the web there are lots of pages with "orthogonal operator, maps" or something like that, and besides any decente linear algebra book must cover it. For any other subspace the definitions are very similar, but in your case it is specially easy as you only have one-dimensional subspaces, so any non-zero vector in any of them is a basis and you only need to normalize.

Comment: In the definition of map $T$, the matrix $P_0$ of order $3\times 3$ and the matrix $(x,y,z)^t$ of order $3\times 1$ the matrix of both product must be $3\times 1$ , why you write it of order $3\times 3$?

Comment: @user275240 That's a mistake I made. In order to save some time I paste and copy from myself and didn't pay attention to that. Thanks, I shall fix it now.

Comment: I understand why you write $\;P_0^2=P_0$ but what is the point of saying $\;P_0w\in V_0\;\;\forall w\in\Bbb C^3\;$ , and if $$v\in V_0\iff v=\begin{pmatrix}a\\a\\a\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\text{then}\;\;P_0v=v$$.

Comment: I just remarked some usual definitions of projections.

Comment: Thanks again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user275240 My pleasure.

Comment: I tried to solve the other map $T_1:\mathbb{C}^3\to V_1$ and $T_2:\mathbb{C}^3\to V_2$ I find $P_1:=\frac{1}{2}\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & -1 \\      0 & 0 & 0 \\     -1 & 0 & 1 \\   \end{array} } \right]$ and $P_2:=\frac{1}{2}\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & -1 & 0 \\      -1 & 1 & 0 \\     0 & 0 & 0 \\   \end{array} } \right]$, respectively. But the condition $P_1\times P_2\neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1,\dotsc,v_m$ be a basis for a subspace $V$ of $\Bbb R^n$ and put the vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_m$ into the columns of a matrix $A$.

The orthogonal projection map $T:\Bbb R^n\to V$ is given by $T(x)=Px$ where
$$
P = A(A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top
$$
In our case, 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
so
$$
P=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence
$$
T(x,y,z)=P\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{bmatrix}
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
\frac{1}{3} \, x + \frac{1}{3} \, y + \frac{1}{3} \, z \\
\frac{1}{3} \, x + \frac{1}{3} \, y + \frac{1}{3} \, z \\
\frac{1}{3} \, x + \frac{1}{3} \, y + \frac{1}{3} \, z
\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: This does not work with $T_1:\mathbb{C}^3\to V_1$ and $T_2:\mathbb{C}^3\to V_2$ .

Comment: @user275240 Yes it does...

Comment: How ? please tell me? the matrix P in $T_1$ has a zero row, so the matrix cannot be invertible.

Comment: Your matrix should not be inventive. In fact, it must have rank one.

Comment: So your method does not work?

Comment: The method does work.